# bootloop without power button

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, adb, recovery-mode

I have a Nexus S which sadly has a broken power button. This means I cannot do anything in recovery mode. Recently, after downgrading from a Cyanogenmod 10.1 nightly to and experimental build, it got stuck in a boot-loop.

I am trying to install ClockworkMod Touch, I think this would probably be the fastest (and most permanent) option. I have an `.img` file, but also a flashable `.zip` file for ClockWorkMod Touch.

The problem is, I am unable to either flash the `.zip`, or install the `.img`, because my PC doesn't detect a device in fast-boot mode.

Does anyone know how to install the zip using ADB, with commands that are available through either regular boot or recovery mode?

I could also try and send keystrokes for the power button through ADB but this wouldn't work in recovery.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Update: The phone wont go into Fastboot-usb mode, I dont know why. (I am not using the original USB cable)

Update 2: I managed to fix the bootloop by reinstalling the ROM using

```
    adb shell
    recovery --update_package=/sdcard/cmupdater/cm-10.1-20130121-EXPERIMENTAL-crespo-M1.zip
```

Still would like to know how to install CWM touch.

Comment: Can you please tell me how were you able to push the ROM without getting into fastboot? I'm stuck in the same situation and I'm getting a device not found error when i try the adb shell command.

Answer (score -2):

Check [this](http://www.firstdroid.com/tutorials/htc-magic-sapphire-tutorials-htc-magic-sapphire-guias/how-to-load-a-rom-with-fastboot/) out. It's a step-by-step guide on how to load a rom with fastboot. Maybe it helps.

Also, additional info can be found on [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) forums.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the problem is my PC doesn't detect my phone while in fastboot mode, so i can't send any commands.

Comment: Take a look at [Universal naked driver](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1379875). Might help. Please read the thread before doing anything.

Comment: The universal naked driver is just a repacked adb drivers, which is pointless because *it got stuck in a boot-loop* which is defeating your answer!